# How do I join the integers together in a list such that: ['a',1,2] becomes ['a',12]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list input as `li = ['a',3,4,'b',6,'c',5,1]` and I want to my output list as `li = ['a',34,'b',6,'c',51]`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't name your list `list`. It is occupied already.

Comment: Thanks for making my attention towards that typing mistake @AntonvBR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using groupby and checking the type of the items.

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['a',3,4,'b',6,'c',5,1]

nlst = [''.join(i) if c == str else int(''.join(map(str,i))) 
            for c, i in groupby(lst, key=type)]

print(nlst)
```

Returns:

```
['a', 34, 'b', 6, 'c', 51]
```

---

**Short explanation**:

The groupby will create these items (the lists are actually returned as generators, but that's not important for now)

```
[(str, ['a']),
 (int, [3, 4]),
 (str, ['b']),
 (int, [6]),
 (str, ['c']),
 (int, [5, 1])]
```

We then either perform a str.join() if str or we map int to str, perform a str.join() and back to int again for int.

Note: that `lst = ['a','b',3,4,'b',6,'c',5,1] # added a 'b'` would return:

```
['ab', 34, 'b', 6, 'c', 51]
```

If that is not desirable you could rewrite the function and this might even make it easier to understand like this:

```
lst = ['a','b',3,4,'b',6,'c',5,1]
nlst = []

for c, i in groupby(lst, key=type):
    if c == int:
        nlst.append(int(''.join(map(str,i))))
    elif c == str:
        nlst.extend(i)
    # If type is not int or str, we skip!
    else:
        pass

print(nlst)
```

Returning:

```
['a', 'b', 34, 'b', 6, 'c', 51]
```

---

**Further reading:**

If you have trouble understanding this solution I'd say you could read more about:

1. Python str.join()   joining strings
2. Python map          converting from one type to another
3. Python types        str, int, list..
4. List comprehensions compact for loops [i for i in list]
5. Itertools groupby   (key function here)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use re:

```
import re

list_ = ['a',3,4,'b',6,'c',5,1]

x = re.split('(\d+)',''.join(str(i) for i in list_))

list_ = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in x if i] # removing empty values and get correct formatting
```

Comment: Yeah, regex is another go, but don't forget to convert back the ints or the answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

With pure recursion:

```
def shrink(l):
  if len(l) <= 1:
    return l
  if type(l[-1]) == int and type(l[-2]) == int:
    l[-2] = int(str(l[-2]) + str(l[-1]))
    return shrink(l[:-1])
  else:
    return shrink(l[:-1]) + [l[-1]]

shrink(lst)
```